# Why does using a relationship consume so much memory?

Tags: sql, database, memory, sqlalchemy

I have an application that uses SQLAlchemy. Here's part of the object model:

```
class HtmlTaggingDataset(Base):
    __tablename__ = "htmlTaggingDatasets"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class TrainingHtml(Base):
    __tablename__ = "trainingHtml"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    datasetId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("htmlTaggingDatasets.id"))

    processingState = Column(Integer)
    originalSrc = Column(String)
    taggedSrc = Column(String)

    dataset = relationship("HtmlTaggingDataset", backref=backref("items", order_by=id))
```

The `originalSrc` and `taggedSrc` are fairly long strings, can be up to several MB.
Now, I want to calculate the number of instances by their `processingState`.
If I do this:

```
    html_datasets = cherrypy.request.db.query(HtmlTaggingDataset).all()
    for ds in html_datasets:
        ds.total = len(ds.items)
        ds.remaining = len([i for i in ds.items if i.processingState == PROCESSING_STATE_NEW])
        ds.in_progress = len([i for i in ds.items if i.processingState == PROCESSING_STATE_IN_PROGRESS])
        ds.flagged = len([i for i in ds.items if i.processingState == PROCESSING_STATE_FLAGGED])
```

then the memory usage increases dramatically. But if I do this:

```
    html_datasets = cherrypy.request.db.query(HtmlTaggingDataset).all()
    for ds in html_datasets:
        items = cherrypy.request.db.query(TrainingHtml).filter_by(datasetId=ds.id)
        ds.total = items.count()
        ds.remaining = items.filter_by(processingState=PROCESSING_STATE_NEW).count()
        ds.in_progress = items.filter_by(processingState=PROCESSING_STATE_IN_PROGRESS).count()
        ds.flagged = items.filter_by(processingState=PROCESSING_STATE_FLAGGED).count()
```

the memory usage stays relatively low.

My question:

1. Why does the memory usage increase in the first case? I'm guessing it's loading each of the objects into memory during the list comprehension lines, right?

   - Why isn't the garbage collector cleaning these up?
2. Is there any way to do this with the convenience of the first case, but without the memory cost?

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your questions:

1. Yes, you are right. It is because you load all the objects into memory.

   - This is because instances of all SA objects which were loaded are kept your `session` until you are done with the whole code.
2. There are many ways. Below I will share just two:

---

**Way-1: [`Deferred Column Loading`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#deferred-column-loading)**
Specifically for the purpose of not loading large columns by default.

*option-1:* one option would be to configure both columns to be `deferred` by default:

```
class TrainingHtml(Base):
    # ...
    originalSrc = deferred(Column(String))
    taggedSrc = deferred(Column(String))
```

*option-2:* second option would be to use a query (like you did, just a bit differently) instead of a relationship navigation and configure it to not load those by default (or actually only configure to load those one cares about (including `primary_key`):

```
html_datasets = cherrypy.request.db.query(HtmlTaggingDataset).all()
for ds in html_datasets:
    # @note: new variable: *ds_items* instead of *ds.items*
    # a) tell query not to load large columns
    ds_items = session.query(TrainingHtml).with_parent(ds).options(defer("originalSrc")).options(defer("taggedSrc")).all()
    # b) tell query to load only relevant columns
    # ds_items = session.query(TrainingHtml).with_parent(ds).options(load_only("id", "processingState")).all()

    ds.total = len(ds_items)
    ds.remaining = len([i for i in ds_items if i.processingState == PROCESSING_STATE_NEW])
    ds.in_progress = len([i for i in ds_items if i.processingState == PROCESSING_STATE_IN_PROGRESS])
    ds.flagged = len([i for i in ds_items if i.processingState == PROCESSING_STATE_FLAGGED])
```

---

**Way-2: Request-specific query;** Completely change a query which in one SQL will get from database only what you need without needing to load objects into memory at all.

Here I would start with something like below:

```
qry = (session.query(
            HtmlTaggingDataset.id,
            TrainingHtml.processingState,
            func.count("*").label("cnt"),
        )
        .join(TrainingHtml)
        .group_by(HtmlTaggingDataset.id, TrainingHtml.processingState)
        .order_by(HtmlTaggingDataset.id) # important for groupby later
        )
```

and then set the values to your `HtmlTaggingDataset` objects accordingly. This is going to be very fast, as all is done in one query (except `total`, which you can easily do in a separate query for all `HtmlTaggingDataset` instances at once).

---

**Way-3: [`Query-enabled properties`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#building-query-enabled-properties)**

Read the documentation, but your properties would look like:

```
class HtmlTaggingDataset(Base):
    __tablename__ = "htmlTaggingDatasets"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    @property
    def total(self):
        return object_session(self).query(TrainingHtml).with_parent(self).count()

    @property
    def remaining(self):
        return object_session(self).query(TrainingHtml).filter(TrainingHtml.processingState == PROCESSING_STATE_NEW).with_parent(self).count()
```

Again, this is similar to your second version, but it is now part of the model. Still the disadvantage is that it performs many `SQL` queries.

**Way-4: [Hybrid Attributes extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html)**

Here you would build an attributes similar to below:

```
class HtmlTaggingDataset(Base):
#....
    @hybrid_property
    def in_progress(self):
        return len([i for i in self.items if i.processingState == PROCESSING_STATE_IN_PROGRESS])

    @in_progress.expression
    def in_progress(cls):
        return select([func.count("*")]).\
                where(TrainingHtml.datasetId == cls.id).\
                where(TrainingHtml.processingState == PROCESSING_STATE_IN_PROGRESS).\
                group_by(TrainingHtml.datasetId).label("in_progress")
```

In this case, if the object is in memory, it will return values by navigating all children. But also you can include those into query directly and then again you can have all data in just one SQL statement, and later in python code you can just set the properties on the dataset instances accordingly:

```
html_datasets = session.query(HtmlTaggingDataset, HtmlTaggingDataset.in_progress, HtmlTaggingDataset.flagged).all()
```

Comment: until "..." means that your http request is processed completely, only then the session might release some objects from memory

Comment: For me, the objects don't seem to be released even when the HTTP request is processed completely. Why would this be the case?

Comment: there is not enough information to answer why this is the case. I expect that when the request handling is completed, in absense of errors the `session` (transaction) is committed, at which point objects are invalidated. But, again, need to know details of your setup of the web request handling etc to answer that. What you can try to do after you got all the data for the request is to call `session.expunge_all()` and see if it helps. In any case I personally would go with another solution for the use case you describe.